# FlashDevelop sound problems

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

My goal is to create an Asteroids clone, I have the game set, as found on the chrism web tutorial. I have the game almost completely set, but, when I add a sound, The program complains with the following errors.

> \src\Main.as(21): col: 3 Error: Access of undefined property soundClip.
>
> \src\Main.as(20): col: 17 Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Sound.

The code is shown here :

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Chris Moeller
     * http://www.chrismweb.com
     * Tutorial: Creating an Asteroids Game: Part 4
     */

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        [Embed(source = "snd/9mmshot.mp3")]

        private const embeddedSound:Class;
        var soundClip:Sound = new embeddedSound(); // Bullet
        soundClip.play(); // Play the sound
        private var game:Game;
        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point

            //create the game object passing in the swf width and height
            game = new Game(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);

            //add the game bitmap to the screen/ Main.as Sprite to make it visible
            addChild(game.bitmap);

            //Create the main game loop
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Run);


            //add keylisteners
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, game.KeyDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, game.KeyUp);

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, game.MouseDown);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, game.MouseUp);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, game.MoveMouse);
        }

        private function Run(e:Event):void
        {
           game.Update();
           game.Render();            
        }   
    }   
}
```

I have tried researching the problem and no luck here, I have even checked some     adding sound tutorials using the program.

I have even reduced the sound quality as found online

but no luck here and I have no idea what's going on. Please Help!!
Any Help would be extremely appreciated!
I used online audio converter to convert the audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid your first error (`Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Sound.`), you have to import the [`Sound`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html) class to your class :

```
// ...

import flash.media.Sound;
```

For the second error, you should know that you can not use your `soundClip` object outside a function, that part is just to declare (and initialize) your objects, so you can do, for example :

```
private function shotFunction(): void 
{
    soundClip.play();
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: The first error was fixed, but, now the program starts complaining with a warning that says, \src\Main.as(21): col: 7 Warning: var 'soundClip' will be scoped to the default namespace: Main: internal.  It will not be visible outside of this package. I now have the following code public class Main extends Sprite 
 {
  [Embed(source = "snd/9mmshot.mp3")]
  
  private const embeddedSound:Class;
  var soundClip:Sound = new embeddedSound(); // Bullet
  private function shotFunction(): void 
{
    soundClip.play();
} Research didn't help, but the errors are gone. Please Help Me!! I almost fixed this!

Comment: @JohnDoeLuis You can make it `public` : `public var soundClip:Sound = new embeddedSound();` ...

Comment: The program now complains with this \src\Main.as(21): col: 19 Error: Attribute is invalid., I'm almost out of the error. Please help!! complete code is here(".public class Main extends Sprite 
 {
  [Embed(source = "snd/9mmshot.mp3")]
  
  private const embeddedSound:Class;
  public : public var soundClip:Sound = new embeddedSound(); // PlaySound
  
  private var game:Game;
  public function Main():void")                                                              .My ultimate goal is to add sounds to the game.

Comment: @JohnDoeLuis It should be `public var soundClip:Sound = new embeddedSound();`, the colon (:) was to explain to you how to set it `public`.

Comment: I sadly get the same error. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, I copied the value and still get the same error. This is the tutorial I used for adding sounds. http://as3tutorialblog.blogspot.com/2009/05/as3-embedding-sounds-in-flashdevelop.html . Please help me!!

Comment: @JohnDoeLuis Could you add your final code with the details of that error at the end of your question ?

Comment: public class Main extends Sprite 
 {
  [Embed(source = "snd/9mmshot.mp3")]
  
  private const embeddedSound:Class;
  public var soundClip:Sound = new embeddedSound(); //Bullet
  soundClip.play(); // Play the sound
  private var game:Game;
  public function Main():void                                                                              \Link to the tutorial  http://chrismweb.com/2011/01/26/creating-an-asteroids-game-part-1-setting-up-flashdevelop-and-planning/ Please Help!

Comment: @JohnDoeLuis I tested the tutorial and it's working fine ! I can't understand what's your problem exactly.

Comment: Hmm, My problem is that I want to add sound when the ship shoots, like the sound effect in space invaders when you shoot enemies.

Comment: @JohnDoeLuis The `soundClip.play();` shouldn't be there !! Concentrate please !! It's really easy to understand. You should use `soundClip.play();` inside a function, like the tutorial ...